# appendChild works outside the function but not inside

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

I have a problem with some part of my code.I try to create "DIV" and "P" tags using JavaScript but it is only working when I put the code outside of the function ( function is called "fo" ).When you click the button, a dialog box appears and if you click cancel, the appendChild method should put "div" and "p" tags inside the "body".

I should add that text in p tag can briefly be seen on the screen and suddenly it vanishes.My browser is Google Chrome.

```
<html>
<body>
</body>
<script> 
function give(){
form = document.createElement("FORM");
input = document.createElement("INPUT");
input.setAttribute("type", "submit");
input.setAttribute("value", "button");
form.setAttribute("id", "abc");
form.setAttribute("onsubmit", "fo()");
textarea = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
textarea.setAttribute("id", "txt");
form.appendChild(input);
form.appendChild(textarea);
document.body.appendChild(form);
document.getElementById("abc").method = "post";
}
  give();
  function fo(){
a = document.getElementById("txt").value; 
cfm = confirm("Are you sure you want changes");
if (cfm == false ) {
div = document.createElement("DIV");
p = document.createElement("P");
ptxt = document.createTextNode("test");
p.setAttribute("id", "centr");
p.appendChild(ptxt);
div.appendChild(p);
document.body.appendChild(div);
}
}
/*When this part of code is outside function fo() , appendChild works correctly
  div = document.createElement("DIV");
  p = document.createElement("P");
  ptxt = document.createTextNode("Outside the function it works");
  p.setAttribute("id", "centr");
  p.appendChild(ptxt);
  div.appendChild(p);
  document.body.appendChild(div); 
  */
  </script>
  </html>
```

Comment: Did you declare your variables (a, cfm, div, p osv) somewhere else before using them in the function?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Can you post your call and a bit of your HTML?

Comment: How do you call your function fo()? If the content appears and disappears it sounds as if it might be called in response to a form submission, which reloads the page.

Comment: What is the actual error you're receiving

Comment: @AndyG I think it is about the same problem, or even that the function is never called in the first place

Comment: There is no error , it just does not do something that it should be doing.

Function is supposed to be called when you click the button.

Comment: What button? Post your code that calls your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You faced with the default behaviour of form submit, which is navigating to page, specified in `action` attribute or reloading current page if `action` not specified.

You need to do following changes to your code to fix this:

1. Modify submit handler registration to `form.setAttribute("onsubmit", "fo(event)");`
2. Change `fo()` function signature to `fo(event)`
3. Call `event.preventDefault()` at the end of `if (cfm == false)` condition body

So your code would look like this:

```
<html>
<body>
</body>
<script>
    function give(){
        form = document.createElement("FORM");
        input = document.createElement("INPUT");
        input.setAttribute("type", "submit");
        input.setAttribute("value", "button");
        form.setAttribute("id", "abc");
        form.setAttribute("onsubmit", "fo(event)");
        textarea = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
        textarea.setAttribute("id", "txt");
        form.appendChild(input);
        form.appendChild(textarea);
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        document.getElementById("abc").method = "post";
    }
    give();
    function fo(event){
        a = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        cfm = confirm("Are you sure you want changes");
        if (cfm == false ) {
            div = document.createElement("DIV");
            p = document.createElement("P");
            ptxt = document.createTextNode("test");
            p.setAttribute("id", "centr");
            p.appendChild(ptxt);
            div.appendChild(p);
            document.body.appendChild(div);
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```